# the created download link to open the link instead of downloading it

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I'm using python selenium to crawl images in chrome. To download the images, I create download links using the following code:

```
script_js = 'var imageURL = document.getElementsByTagName("{select_tag}")[{num}].getAttribute("src");' \
            'var link = document.createElement("a"); ' \
            'link.download = "{image_name}";' \
            'link.href = imageURL;' \
            'link.innerHTML = "download";' \
            'document.body.appendChild(link);' \
            'link.click();' \
            'document.body.removeChild(link);' \
            'delete link;'.format(select_tag="img", num=0, image_name=f"{order+1}.jpg")
browser.execute_script(script_js)
```

I have successfully downloaded images using this method on other sites before. But this time, it doesn't work.

When I created the download link and clicked on it, the browser opened the image in the current tab instead of downloading it.

I tried to get the url of a single image in the page and open it in the new tab. Then, I created the download link in the same way and found that it worked.

I am curious why it cannot be downloaded on the original page. Since these images require login to view, is this an antiscrape method.

Is there any way to create a download link which download successfully in the original page?

I'm sorry that I can't provide the original site because it requires login.

Oh, I forget to mention that the src attribute of the image looks like this: "img/a175/321F2061A9895…". So, I think the image is served from the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see it, you can download it... either directly or via screenshot of the images themselves. You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) (A Python framework) to do it. `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the script below with `python` or `pytest`.

The first test downloads images directly from a website. The second test takes a mini-screenshot of just the image, and then saves it.

```py
"""Use SeleniumBase to download images and verify."""
import os
from seleniumbase import BaseCase


class DownloadImages(BaseCase):
    def test_download_images_directly(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/chart_maker/")
        img_elements_with_src = self.find_elements("img[src]")
        unique_src_values = []
        for img in img_elements_with_src:
            src = img.get_attribute("src")
            if src not in unique_src_values:
                unique_src_values.append(src)
        print()
        for src in unique_src_values:
            if src.split(".")[-1] not in ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]:
                continue
            self.download_file(src)  # Goes to downloaded_files/
            filename = src.split("/")[-1]
            self.assert_downloaded_file(filename)
            folder = "downloaded_files"
            file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            self._print(file_path)

    def test_download_images_via_screenshot(self):
        self.open("seleniumbase.io/error_page/")
        img_elements_with_src = self.find_elements("img[src]")
        unique_src_values = []
        for img in img_elements_with_src:
            src = img.get_attribute("src")
            if src not in unique_src_values:
                unique_src_values.append(src)
        print()
        count = 0
        for src in unique_src_values:
            self.open(src)
            if not self.headless and not self.headless2:
                self.highlight("img", loops=1)
            image = self.find_element("img")
            if src.startswith("data:") or ";base64" in src:
                # Special Cases: SVGs, etc. Convert to PNG.
                count += 1
                filename = "svg_image_%s.png" % count
            else:
                filename = src.split("/")[-1]
            folder = "downloaded_files"
            file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            image.screenshot(file_path)
            self.assert_downloaded_file(filename)
            self._print(file_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__])
```

Here's the current output of that: (If those websites change, the images downloaded may change.)

```
downloaded_files/logo3c.png
downloaded_files/logo6.png
downloaded_files/sample_pie_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_column_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_bar_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_line_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_area_chart.png
downloaded_files/multi_series_chart.png
.
downloaded_files/svg_image_1.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_2.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_3.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_4.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_5.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_6.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_7.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_8.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_9.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_10.png
downloaded_files/svg_image_11.png
```

Comment: I barely know about SeleniumBase. But when I run the your code, I found that the image seems to be encoded to Base64 before downloading. It can be done by using JS HTML5 Canvas. Thanks. I just want to know why I can't download the image in the original page.